# The product topology is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In *theorem 3.16 Banach-Alaoglu-Bourbaki* in Brezis's book of Functional Analysis, the author said that the product topology is "the same as the topology of pointwise convergence". I'm trying to prove this result, i.e.,

> Let $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ be a collection of topological spaces. We endow $E := \prod_{i\in I} E_i$ with the product topology. Let $f \in E$ and $(f_d)_{d\in D}$ be a net in $E$. Then $f_d \to f$ if and only if $f^{(i)}_d \to f^{(i)}$ for all $i \in I$.

I post my proof as an answer below. Could you have a check on my attempt?

Comment: Is this a strategy for increasing your reputation? Why not post the solution with the question? Sometimes a problem statement can be incomplete and overlook a trivial counter-example. Other times, there could be a flaw in the solution. It doesn't make sense for you to have to make changes in two places nor does it make sense for reviewers to comment in two places.

Comment: @JohnDouma Oh no. Reputation means nothing to me. I posted them separately so that I can accept my own answer (in case other people only gives comments) to remove my question from unanswered list. Surely, other people can post answers and I will accept theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\pi_i: E \to E_i$ be the projection map. By definition of product topology, $\pi_i$ is continuous for all $i \in I$. It follows from $f_d \to f$ that $f_d^{(i)} = \pi_i (f_d) \to \pi_i (f) = f^{(i)}$.

Let $f^{(i)}_d \to f^{(i)}$ for all $i \in I$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood (nbh) of $f$ in $E$. By definition of product topology, there is a sequence $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $f^{(i)} \in U_i$, $U_i$ is open in $E_i$, $\prod_{i\in I} U_i \subseteq U$, and there are finitely many $i$'s such that $U_i \neq E_i$. WLOG, let $i_1, \ldots, i_n$ be those $i$'s such that $U_i \neq E_i$. Then for each $k \in \{1,2,\ldots n\}$ there is $d_k \in D$ such that $f_d^{(i_k)} \in U_{i_k}$ for all $d \ge d_k$. Let $\overline d$ be in $D$ auch that for all $i=1,\ldots n$ $\overline{d} \ge d_i$. Then  $f_d^{(i_k)} \in U_{i_k}$ for all $d \ge \overline d$ and $k = 1, \ldots, n$. It follows that $f_d \in U$ for all $d \ge \overline d$. This completes the proof.

Comment: There need not be a max, but there *is* a common upperbound from directnedness.  Don' t make the max claim! It's a common mistake I see on the site in net proofs. Also notationwise $d_k$ is not very handy. Intruduce $k$ first. (in $\{1,2,\ldots n\}$ presumably?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You're right. I misunderstood that $d_k$ is natural number :((

Comment: You want $d_1,\ldots, d_n$ (in $D$) that correspond to $i_1, \ldots i_n \in I$ that form the finite index set used for the base element. I made an edit to show my suggestions for a better write-up.